# Line 27: expected primary expression before & token

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an address book but I keep getting "`expected primary expression before '&' token`".
I also want to be able to edit and create more then one address entry!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct addressinfo
{
    string Name;
    string Address;
    string Phonenumber;
};
addressinfo info;

addressinfo gna(addressinfo& info) {// get new address
    addressinfo accessinfo;
    info.Name;
    info.Address;
    info.Phonenumber;
    return accessinfo;
}

void address_menu() {
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        addressinfo info = gna(addressinfo& info);
        break;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you say which line it's on?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that my formatting either got rekd when I copied and pasted it or its just the way i write code

Comment: Well, see how it looks properly formatted.

Comment: IS it hard to understand my code or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`addressinfo info = gna(addressinfo& info)` should be `addressinfo info = gna(info)` because you're *calling* a function, not creating one.

Comment: Can I contact you for further advice via pm?

Comment: Heh, what a silly mistake I made. Thanks for helping me point out the obvious! :)